# Pandas - copy dataframe base on values in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, repeat

Assuming I have this simple df:

```
    A  B
0   1  2
1   3  4
```

Now I want to add a new column, `C`, That gets the values, lets say ['Orange', 'Apple'],
And I want to replicate the whole df, once for 'Orange' and once for 'Apple',
So that my final result would look like that:

```
    A  B     C
0   1  2  Orange
1   3  4  Orange
3   1  2  Apple
4   3  4  Apple
```

Is their a built-in one-liner in pandas that allows me to do that?
I'm currently using a for loop, and appending the results...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case try with `merge` with `cross`

```
m = pd.DataFrame({'C':['Orange','Apple']})
df.merge(m,how='cross')
Out[151]: 
   A  B       C
0  1  2  Orange
1  1  2   Apple
2  3  4  Orange
3  3  4   Apple
```